# Accessing Action information in the View

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am dynamically building a menu on my main _Layout using

```
 @{Html.RenderAction("PageMenu", "Service");}
```

which adds an Menu Item for each page

```
@model int

<ul id="pages">
    @for (var i = 1; i <= Model; i++) {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Page " + i,"Page", "Service", new { page = @i}, null)/li>
    }
</ul>
```

What I need to know is which page I am actually on so that I can indicate that on the menu. Is there someway I can access the page # for the last clicked ActionLink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could retrieve the current page number from the `RouteData`:

```
@model int

@functions {
    IDictionary<string, object> GetHtmlAttributes(int i) {
        var routeData = ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData;
        int currentPage = 0;
        string page = routeData.Values["page"] as string;
        var htmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary();
        if (int.TryParse(page, out currentPage) && currentPage == i)
        {
            htmlAttributes["class"] = "active";
        }
        return htmlAttributes;
    }
}

<ul id="pages">
    @for (var i = 1; i <= Model; i++) 
    {
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink(
                "Page " + i,
                "Page", 
                "Service", 
                new RouteValueDictionary(new { page = i }), 
                GetHtmlAttributes(i)
            )
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Notice how I am using the `ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData` property instead of `ViewContext.RouteData` in order to get the parent view context since you are inside a child action (you used the `Html.RenderAction` helper).

Comment: With some tweaking around routeData.Values["id"], I got it returning the page number but it only ever returns page 1, even if I just clicked on page 3?